# What is the Kubernetes Pod EmptyDir Volume Capacity?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create an emptyDir volume for my k8s pod, and was wondering what the maximum capacity is? I am not specifying a limit as I want to get the max storage possible, and will implementing a purging mechanism at the limit.

Answer (score 1):

If no size is specified, [memory backed volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) are sized to 50% of the memory on the Kubernetes node.